# ¿Cómo paso parámetros a una funcion JS en un código de PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, funciones, parametros

en mi index.php tengo mi sección html y mi sección con PHP, dentro de `<?php ?>`, tengo la siguiente linea:

```
echo '<div class="perfilhome">

<p>@'.$user.'</p>
<img src="'.$ruta.'"  class="fotoperfil" alt="" onclick="abrircerrar('menulat')">

</div>';
```

Lo que sucede es que a menulat me lo toma como si fuera código PHP (lo marca de color violeta), y yo quiero que me lo tome como código HTML (que vendría a ser un parámetro), al suceder esto, no estoy pasando ningún parámetro a la funcion abrircerrar, ya intente quitando las comillas simples y no funciona, ¿Qué tengo que hacer?.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que abres con comillas, simples, al poner comillas simples nuevamente no las toma dentro del html, sino que estás cerrando dichas comillas simples.

para que aparezcan como código html, simplemente tienes que escaparlas con `\` antes del símbolo

```
echo '<div class="perfilhome">

<p>@'.$user.'</p>
<img src="'.$ruta.'"  class="fotoperfil" alt="" onclick="abrircerrar(\'menulat\')">

</div>';
```

Esto lo hará cadena de texto, pero si es un parámetro, o el nombre de una variable y no una cadena de texto entonces basta con quitar las comillas

```
echo '<div class="perfilhome">

<p>@'.$user.'</p>
<img src="'.$ruta.'"  class="fotoperfil" alt="" onclick="abrircerrar(menulat)">

</div>';
```